# Divide Spring configuration across multiple projects

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-2

we have quite a few projects that use the same codebase (backend code).
Just the frontend tends to be different.
We decided that the best approach would be to seperate backend and frontend into different projects: **Engine** and **Project_name**

Now these are Spring-projects. So it would only seem logical if we divide the Spring configurations aswell:
**Database.xml**, **Services.xml** would belong to the project **Engine**.
And a specific **Frontend.xml** would belong to **Project_Name**.
To link these up, I would need a generic **SpringBeans.xml** that imports all of these XML's.

I tried following directory structure:

**Engine Project**

- Config

  - *Spring*

    - Database.xml
    - Services.xml

**Project_Name Project**

- Config

  - SpringBeans.xml
  - *spring*

    - Frontend.xml

The contents of SpringBeans.xml are simply:

```
    <import resource="spring/Database.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/Services.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/Frontend.xml"/>
```

I set up Eclipse so the Project_Name project references the Engine project.
When I start it, SpringBeans.xml gets found, however the XML files in the Engine project aren't found (FileNotFoundException).
I'll also note that before splitting up the Engine and Frontend code into different projects, the principle of importing other XML files worked like a charm.

So my question to you: Is it possible to make different Spring configrations in different projects play together nicely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the spring bean configuration files are in the classpath, you need to add the prefix claspath to the resource location:

> ```
> <import resource="classpath:spring/Database.xml"/>
> <import resource="classpath:spring/Services.xml"/>
> <import resource="classpath:spring/Frontend.xml"/>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried it, but a first glance still gives the FileNotFoundException. I'll start by figuring out if the classpath is well defined

Comment: Ah indeed it was the classpath. I'll have to make my Engine project a Maven project. Then import that using Maven dependecies. I'll accept your answer since it perfectly answers the question. Thanks