# How to import spring-config.xml of one project into spring-config.xml of another project?

Tags: java, spring

I have two projects with the name `simple-core-impl` and `simple-core-web`. Both projects are `spring based` and both have a parent project name `simple-core`. I have `simple-impl-config.xml` in `simple-core-impl` project and `simple-web-config.xml` in `simple-impl-config.xml`.

I have a bean which has class: `simple service` which have one method which returns me a message "hello World". I want to import the `simple-impl-config.xml` in the `simple-web-config.xml` so the bean is available into my controller which is in `simple-core-web` project.

`simple-core-web` project has a jar of `simple-core-impl` project.

So please tell me how I can I import `spring-config.xml` of one project into `spring-config.xml` of another project so all the beans of first is available into other project by just importing? I do not want to rewrite all the beans.

Comment: Future readers, in case you have a "I think what I wrote should work" issue, also see this bug, with a "status=declined".  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16017   Just in case the URL ever eventually fails, the title of the bug post is " Import of an XML file from the root of a JAR file with wildcard classpath and wildcard path does not work [SPR-11390] "

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
<import resource="classpath:spring-config.xml" />
```

**Reference:**

- [Composing XML-based configuration
  metadata](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import)
- [Resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) (here the `classpath:`
  part is explained)

Comment: And if I have the same situation but only using annotated configuration classes instead of spring-config.xml what can I do?

Comment: @Aditzu use `@Import` to import your other `@Configuration` classes.

Answer (score 63):

A small variation of Sean's answer:

```
<import resource="classpath*:spring-config.xml" />
```

With the asterisk in order to spring search files 'spring-config.xml' anywhere in the classpath.

Another reference:
[Divide Spring configuration across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092133/divide-spring-configuration-across-multiple-projects)

[Spring classpath prefix difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference)

Comment: does the classpath*: apply if is inside another module ?

Comment: Note that the use of * does not throw any error if 0 files are found in the classpath.

Answer (score 10):

For some reason, import as suggested by Ricardo didnt work for me. I got it working with following statement:

`<import resource="classpath*:/spring-config.xml" />`

Answer (score 8):

Here is the annotation based example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring-config.xml"})
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<import resource="classpath*:spring-config.xml" />
```

This is the most suitable one for class path configuration.
Particularly when you are searching for the .xml files in a different project which is in your class path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the jar/war of the module B in the module A and add the classpath in your new spring-module file. Just add this line

spring-moduleA.xml  - is a file in module A under the resource folder. By adding this line, it imports all the bean definition from module A to module B.

MODULE B/ spring-moduleB.xml

---

```
import resource="classpath:spring-moduleA.xml"/>

<bean id="helloBeanB" class="basic.HelloWorldB">
  <property name="name" value="BMVNPrj" />
</bean>
```