# what classpath do in web.xml?

Tags: web.xml

I come across this code in my web.xml but I don't understand what it does.

```xml
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:my-main-spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

May I know what classpath do in web.xml? Where can I find more reference or reading material on this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for asking stupid question, I already got my answer from this thread > [How to import spring-config.xml of one project into spring-config.xml of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113579/how-to-import-spring-config-xml-of-one-project-into-spring-config-xml-of-another).