# How to connect spring config with webflow config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

My main config file :

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's my webflow config :

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
          <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
   </bean>

   <webflow-config:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
          <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
   </bean>

     <webflow-config:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
            <webflow-config:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/webflow_sample.xml"/>
     </webflow-config:flow-registry>


     <bean class="com.springapp.mvc.Person" id="person"/>
```

Note that Spring MVC works. I just don't know how to connect webflow config to main config file. I have tried adding it as init param, but that doesn't work. Intelij tells me that 'Application context not found for webflow config' in the top. I was following reference on Spring site, but I can't understand how to connect them.

Answer (score 1):

We list both files in the DispatcherServlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/webmvc-config.xml
            /WEB-INF/config/webflow-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your 'main' Spring config file... simply use an 'import' tag to bring in another xml config. Like So:

[How to import spring-config.xml of one project into spring-config.xml of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113579/how-to-import-spring-config-xml-of-one-project-into-spring-config-xml-of-another)