# How to import spring-context from one sub-module to another sub-module in maven project?

Tags: spring

I  need one help. i am trying to create a Spring moven project in multiple module. just assume, there is Maven project with below module:
Module-root(parent Module of all submodule)
Module-persistance(Having code logic for DAO operation and package type jar)
Module-service(Having code logic for controller implementation and package type war)

Module-service is dependent on Module-persistance submodule.
Module-persistance is having Spring-context1.xml file in it's src/main/resources classpath.
Module-service is having spring-context2.xml file in it's src/main/resources classpath.

### So, My question is how spring-context2.xml can import Spring-context1.xml? Thanks in Advance!

Now importing of the spring.xml file from one module to another working fine :).

But but here i am getting error while deploying the war.

HibernateCfg.java is a file defined in module Module-persistance.
and imported this file in the Module-service. compile and build of the all module is successful. but at the time of deploying the Module-service war file on the server, it is throwing ClassNotFoundException for "HibernateCfg".

I checked the war file, inside of that Module-persistance.jar file is available with class file of HibernateCfg. 
but i am not sure why it is throwing exception. Could you please help me with this.
Below is the exception:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.munsiji.hibernateUtil.HibernateCfg from [Module "deployment.munsiji-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 48 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import spring-config.xml of one project into spring-config.xml of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113579/how-to-import-spring-config-xml-of-one-project-into-spring-config-xml-of-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to the child xml document

```
<import resource="classpath:second-config.xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jeryl For your comment. it helped me. 
but here i am getting error while deploying the war, and i have updated that in the question. Could you help me in that? Thanks again!

Comment: can you accept my answer. and update or make new question about the .war deployment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in maven child project.
If you have written as :

```
    <import resource="second-config.xml" />
```

change it to :

```
    <import resource="classpath:second-config.xml" />
```

Comment: Could you explain why? Also, I think this is dependent upon how you set up your POM.xml